# org.hibernate.query.SemanticException: A query exception occurred

Tags: java, exception, jpa

I am doing a @GetMapping request to search a product using multiple parameters.

My ProductController.java

```
@GetMapping("/search")
    ResponseEntity<ResponseObject> findBySearch(@RequestParam(required = false) Integer productId,
                                                @RequestParam(required = false) String productName,
                                                @RequestParam(required = false) Integer brandId,
                                                @RequestParam(required = false) Integer categoryId,
                                                @RequestParam(required = false) Integer modelYear) {
        List<Product> foundProducts = repository.findProductBySearch(productId, productName, brandId, categoryId, modelYear);
        return (!foundProducts.isEmpty()) ?
                ResponseEntity.status(HttpStatus.OK).body(new ResponseObject(HttpStatus.OK.toString(), "Query successfully", foundProducts))
                :
                ResponseEntity.status(HttpStatus.NOT_FOUND).body(new ResponseObject(HttpStatus.NOT_FOUND.toString(), "Cannot find product with provided model", ""));
    }
```

My ProductRepository.java

```
@Query("SELECT p FROM Products p WHERE (:productId is null or p.productId = :productId) and " +
            "(:p.productName is null or p.productName = :productName) and " +
            "(:p.brandId is null or p.brandId = :brandId) and " +
            "(:p.categoryId is null or p.categoryId = :categoryId) and " +
            "(:p.modelYear is null or p.modelYear = :modelYear)")
    List<Product> findProductBySearch(@Param("productId") Integer productId,
                                      @Param("productName") String productName,
                                      @Param("brandId") Integer brandId,
                                      @Param("categoryId") Integer categoryId,
                                      @Param("modelYear") Integer modelYear);
```

My Product.java

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "Products")
public class Product {
    @Id
    @SequenceGenerator(
            name = "product_sequence",
            sequenceName = "product_sequence",
            allocationSize = 1
    )
    @GeneratedValue (
            strategy = GenerationType.SEQUENCE,
            generator = "product_sequence"
    )
    @Column(name = "product_id")
    int productId;
    @Column(name = "product_name")
    String productName;
    @Column(name = "brand_id")
    int brandId;
    @Column(name = "category_id")
    int categoryId;
    @Column(name = "model_year")
    int modelYear;
    @Column(name = "list_price")
    double listPrice;

//getters, setters
```

When I run project, it produced this error

**org.hibernate.query.SemanticException: A query exception occurred [SELECT p FROM Products p WHERE (:productId is null or p.productId = :productId) and (:p.productName is null or p.productName = :productName) and (:p.brandId is null or p.brandId = :brandId) and (:p.categoryId is null or p.categoryId = :categoryId) and (:p.modelYear is null or p.modelYear = :modelYear)]**

Please help me to find where I got it wrong.

Comment: Can you add the complete error log?

Comment: `:p.productName` there should be no `:`. Same for the other fields. `:` should only be followed by the actual parameter name

Comment: Your entity is named `Product` not `Products` and as you are writing a JPQL and not a SQL you need to reference the entity not the table. Also `:p.categoryId` is where you probably wanted to write `:categoryId` to check if the passed in parameter was `null` or not. The same applies to your other fields as well.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One of the errors in the query is with the `:p.productName is null`, change it to `(p.productName is null or p.productName = :productName)`

The `:p.productName` is a named parameter and the named parameters are expected to have a value, since `:p.productName` is not provided with a the exception is thrown. It should be either the property name in the bean if you are using HQL, or it should be the column name from the table if you are using a native query.

The same is happening for other columns like `:p.brandId`, `:p.categoryId`, and `:p.modelYear`, so you should do it for other columns as well, the correct query will be

```
@Query("SELECT p FROM Product p WHERE " +
            "(p.productId is null or p.productId = :productId) and " +
            "(p.productName is null or p.productName = :productName) and " +
            "(p.brandId is null or p.brandId = :brandId) and " +
            "(p.categoryId is null or p.categoryId = :categoryId) and " +
            "(p.modelYear is null or p.modelYear = :modelYear)")
```

Comment: That is the only part that would not throw an error. It just doesn't do what it should. `:p.productName`, `:p.brandId`, `:p.categoryId` and `:p.modelYear` are causing the error. Your "correct" query is still wrong

Comment: Thank you you two for help me. The problem is solved by you. I followed instructions on Baeldung, maybe it has some mistakes.

Answer (score 0):

I think you have problem with your query, here is the reasons:

Look at the other `WHERE` statements for example `and (:p.productName is null or p.productName = :productName)` at this point you are putting `:p` which means it should be a parameter rather than column. By writing `:p.productName` it means that you are accessing property `.productName` from parameter `:p` which is not exist. The right syntax to compare **input parameter** with **value of column** is `and (p.productName is null or p.productName = :productName)`. Also you can make it more simple `and (p.productName = :productName)` by this way it will compare for null value or not.

When you need to check the input parameter and the table column as well you can do like this way:

```
and (:productName is null or p.productName = :productName)
```

or

```
and (:productName is not null or p.productName = :productName)
```

This is the example:

```
select
    p
from
    Products p
where
    (p.productId is null
        or p.productId = :productId)
    and (p.productName is null
        or p.productName = :productName)
    and (p.brandId is null
        or p.brandId = :brandId)
    and (p.categoryId is null
        or p.categoryId = :categoryId)
    and (p.modelYear is null
        or p.modelYear = :modelYear)
```

Other exsample:

```
select
    p
from
    Products p
where
    (:productId is null
        or p.productId = :productId)
    and (:productName is null
        or p.productName = :productName)
    and (:brandId is null
        or p.brandId = :brandId)
    and (:categoryId is null
        or p.categoryId = :categoryId)
    and (:modelYear is null
        or p.modelYear = :modelYear)
```

Hope it helps.